# How to interpolate weekly data to hourly?

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I have a dataset containing weekly observations from 2020-01-05 to 2022-12-25. It looks like the following:

```
datetime     NO3   NO1   NO2   NO5   NO4 fyllingsgrad
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 2020-11-29 0.930 0.972 0.978 0.932 0.903        0.972
 2 2021-01-03 0.770 0.821 0.884 0.769 0.785        0.821
 3 2020-04-26 0.264 0.196 0.483 0.268 0.322        0.196
 4 2021-05-09 0.253 0.151 0.453 0.185 0.430        0.151
 5 2021-10-03 0.708 0.761 0.550 0.588 0.809        0.761
 6 2022-03-13 0.364 0.190 0.311 0.242 0.505        0.190
 7 2021-01-17 0.671 0.698 0.814 0.667 0.730        0.698
 8 2021-07-11 0.724 0.772 0.667 0.593 0.731        0.772
 9 2020-12-27 0.813 0.862 0.909 0.808 0.811        0.862
10 2021-06-20 0.693 0.717 0.659 0.506 0.648        0.717
```

I need to interpolate the NO2 variable from the weekly time resolution to hourly. Do anyone know how this could be done?

I have tried multiple things but it doesn´t work. An example is the following code:

```
hour_dat <- data.frame(
  datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2020-01-05"), as.POSIXct("2022-12-25"), by = "1 hour")
)

new_interp <- hour_dat %>% 
  mutate(NO2_interp = approx(x = mag_data$datetime, y = mag_data$NO2, xout = datetime, method = "linear")$y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`approx` does only interpolate, not extrapolate, so `hour_dat` can only be in ranges of `dat` (which probably is the case with your real data). `datetime` should be the same `POSIXct` format. Just `merge` it top `dat` and use `approx in an` lapply`.

```
dat$datetime <- as.POSIXct(dat$datetime)

hour_dat <- data.frame(datetime=seq(as.POSIXct("2020-11-29"), as.POSIXct("2021-06-20"), by="1 hour"))

ndat <- merge(dat, hour_dat, all=TRUE) 

ndat[-1] <- lapply(ndat[-1], \(y) approx(ndat$datetime, y, xout=ndat$datetime)$y)
```

Note, that this is *linear* interpolation.

#### Gives

```
head(ndat)
#              datetime       NO3       NO1       NO2       NO5       NO4 fyllingsgrad
# 1 2020-04-26 02:00:00 0.2640000 0.1960000 0.4830000 0.2680000 0.3220000    0.1960000
# 2 2020-11-29 00:00:00 0.9298721 0.9718510 0.9779050 0.9318725 0.9028884    0.9718510
# 3 2020-11-29 01:00:00 0.9300000 0.9720000 0.9780000 0.9320000 0.9030000    0.9720000
# 4 2020-11-29 02:00:00 0.9298259 0.9718363 0.9778973 0.9318155 0.9028631    0.9718363
# 5 2020-11-29 03:00:00 0.9296518 0.9716726 0.9777946 0.9316310 0.9027262    0.9716726
# 6 2020-11-29 04:00:00 0.9294777 0.9715089 0.9776920 0.9314464 0.9025893    0.9715089
```

We can quickly check graphically

```
matplot(ndat[-1], type='l', lty=1)
legend('topright', legend=names(ndat)[-1], lty=1, col=1:6, ncol=2, cex=.8, bty='n')
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(datetime = c("2020-11-29", "2021-01-03", "2020-04-26", 
"2021-05-09", "2021-10-03", "2022-03-13", "2021-01-17", "2021-07-11", 
"2020-12-27", "2021-06-20"), NO3 = c(0.93, 0.77, 0.264, 0.253, 
0.708, 0.364, 0.671, 0.724, 0.813, 0.693), NO1 = c(0.972, 0.821, 
0.196, 0.151, 0.761, 0.19, 0.698, 0.772, 0.862, 0.717), NO2 = c(0.978, 
0.884, 0.483, 0.453, 0.55, 0.311, 0.814, 0.667, 0.909, 0.659), 
    NO5 = c(0.932, 0.769, 0.268, 0.185, 0.588, 0.242, 0.667, 
    0.593, 0.808, 0.506), NO4 = c(0.903, 0.785, 0.322, 0.43, 
    0.809, 0.505, 0.73, 0.731, 0.811, 0.648), fyllingsgrad = c(0.972, 
    0.821, 0.196, 0.151, 0.761, 0.19, 0.698, 0.772, 0.862, 0.717
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```